# How should answers specify text that should be replaced?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

When I'm writing answers that include code snippets, I often need to differentiate between text that is required and text that needs to be replaced. With a command like `cp source dest` I have seen a number of different ways that users have attempted to communicate this, such as:

- [keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387546/10376320): `cp path/to/source/file /path/to/destination/file`
- [angle brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132256/10376320): `cp <file1> <file2>`

Is there a recommended method?

Comment: The less lazy answer is usually preferred, all other things equal ;)

Comment: Both the keywords and angle brackets seem decent and common enough. I don't think there is some sort of official method here.

Comment: Angle brackets have a disadvantage that without an explicit statement, it's not always clear whether the angle brackets are supposed to be removed. A new programmer may not immediately realize that the angle brackets should be removed in `cp <file1> <file2>` and kept in `#include <headername.h>`.

Comment: I usually use italicised descriptive names. More obvious if they're mixed in with some actual parameters. And if I could work out how to do it in a comment I'd give an example.

Comment: foo and bar are always handy.

Comment: @HansPassant at that point, they are as obvious as calling your index in your `for` loop `i`. :)

Comment: It's not code snippets, rather command line. Those are already have documentation somewhere, stick to documentation syntax at best: [cp foo.txt bar.txt](https://shapeshed.com/unix-cp/). Disregards, this situation is very similar to pseudo-code, sometimes it's good, sometimes it's bad. The best is to use documentation standards, whatever they are. Imho both methods you describe are.. bad. Beginners may try `cp C:\A/to/source/FILE1.TXT /C:\B/to/destination/FILE2.TXT` or `cp <C:\A\FILE1.TXT> <C:\B\FILE2.TXT>`. If you introduce *your* pseudo-syntax to simplify things, then also explain it.

Comment: @Sinatr Shell commands are code.

Answer (score 23):

The intuitive way is the most coherent method related to your language.
It should be obvious for people willing to answer you. A method related to your language is great because they are already familiar with the technology.

A line with field to be replaced is a template.
You can use the templating synthax of your language if there is one.
If your technology use `<% name %>` or `{name}` for templating, follow this convention.

Another idea, would be to follow your technology's documentation.
For example in your case `man cp` use `cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST`,
so a good option would have to write `cp FILE1 FILE2`.

We are not talking about what is the best. We want to communicate the meaning to readers. No need to change. If this is good enough for the language, it is enough for your question.

Comment: `We want to communicate the meaning to readers.` This is the most important part. Pick the option that you feel has the least potential for confusion in that specific context for the broadest group of readers and go with it. Conventions can help with this (e.g. the man page part) but there is no universal recommendation for all cases beyond this.

Comment: Tangentially, some askers will use their own formatting for text that should be replaced in the body of their question - I generally find myself re-using that same formatting to minimize confusion both amongst the askers as well as future readers. While it might seem good on paper, a standardized convention for this may be more confusing than it's worth, especially for newer contributors.

Answer (score 13):

Regardless of the convention you use for the placeholder identifier text, you may want to also consider italicizing the substitutions for additional clarity. Unfortunately, this is only possible if you manually write out the HTML for the code block yourself, which can be inconvenient.

Don't worry, this won't break code syntax highlighting, as long as your placeholder is valid syntax.

```bash
cp -iL $SOURCE $DESTINATION # copy the thing
```

```html
<pre><code>cp -iL <i>$SOURCE</i> <i>$DESTINATION</i> # copy the thing</code></pre>
```

```java
class YourClass extends YourSuper { ... }
```

```html
<pre><code>class <i>YourClass</i> extends <i>YourSuper</i> { ... }</code></pre>
```

This might not stand out in all fonts, but if you're using a monospace font with a proper distinct italic character style (rather than generated pseudo-italic or oblique style), it can make the substitutions much clearer.

Comment: I see your syntax highlighting example, which is great; is the issue just that there is no syntax highlighting built in to StackOverflow for bash? Even when I wrap the line in <pre><code> no highlighting appears.

Comment: @enharmonic Google Code Prettify claims to support Bash, but it seems very limited. Modified the example to use a comment, which does seem to be highlighted correctly.

Answer (score 6):

The difficulties of all sorts of special characters and "(custom) template syntax" have already been pointed out. Sophisticated formatting with HTML may be one option that is applicable in some cases, when bold and italic text makes it easier to spot the text that has to be replaced. But in many cases it can probably help to explicitly **say** what has to be replaced.

For example:

> If your header is called `example.h`, then you can include it with
>
> ```
> #include <example.h>
> ```

Another example:

> If you want to create a git tag named `v1.4`, with a comment like `this is my version 1.4`, then you can type
>
> ```
> git tag -a v1.4 -m 'this is my version 1.4'
> ```

<sup>(Git is one example where this is notoriously difficult: There are names that are used by convention, but whenever something like `origin`, `master` or `upstream` appears in a command, it's important to know that these might as well be called differently)</sup>

Re-stating what exactly has to be replaced could be done in addition to the formatting. Additionally, it allows to unpack any "template syntax" that has been used with an example:

> You can copy a source file to a destination file with
>
> ```
> cp <source> <destination>
> ```
>
> For example, when your source file is `path/to/source/file` and it should be copied to `/path/to/destination/file`, then this can be done with
>
> ```
> cp path/to/source/file /path/to/destination/file
> ```